# Why is this switch formula returning #N/A?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The string it's searching (A2) is:

`<Column Name="Col1" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />`

```
=SWITCH(A2, ISNUMBER(FIND("Int32", A2)), "Int32", ISNUMBER(FIND("DateTime", A2)), "DateTime",  ISNUMBER(FIND("String", A2)), "String",  ISNUMBER(FIND("Double", A2)), "Double",  ISNUMBER(FIND("Decimal", A2)), "Decimal",  ISNUMBER(FIND("Boolean", A2)), "Boolean")
```

It should return Int32 but instead it returns `#N/A`.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is a xml format, you could use FILTERXML function as in,

In `B2`, enter formula :

```
=FILTERXML(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"System.",""),"//@Type")
```

[image]

Comment: Even better, very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TRUE` as the first argument:

```
=SWITCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(FIND("Int32", A2)), "Int32", ISNUMBER(FIND("DateTime", A2)), "DateTime",  ISNUMBER(FIND("String", A2)), "String",  ISNUMBER(FIND("Double", A2)), "Double",  ISNUMBER(FIND("Decimal", A2)), "Decimal",  ISNUMBER(FIND("Boolean", A2)), "Boolean")
```

The problem is that in its current form, you're attempting to compare the entire text of `A2` to the result of `ISNUMBER(FIND())`, which is a boolean.

Another option is `IFS`:

```
=IFS(ISNUMBER(FIND("Int32", A2)), "Int32", ISNUMBER(FIND("DateTime", A2)), "DateTime",  ISNUMBER(FIND("String", A2)), "String",  ISNUMBER(FIND("Double", A2)), "Double",  ISNUMBER(FIND("Decimal", A2)), "Decimal",  ISNUMBER(FIND("Boolean", A2)), "Boolean")
```

but.... a much nicer solution from @ScottCraner using `LET` and `FILTER`:

```
=@LET(x,{"Int32","DateTime","String","Double","Decimal","Boolean"},FILTER(x,ISNUMBER(FIND(x,A2))))
```